# Yii 1.1 paths not working on remote server

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I'm new to Yii and i'm having troubles setting up the config on a remote server. 
Locally, everything works great, but on the server, using the exact same GH repo including config/main.php, none of the links seem to work.

for example , in site/index, i have a link to /video/index
however, whenever i click the link, the path is added like : /site/video/index. and pressing it repeatedly will add more /video/ in front.(/site/video/video/video/video/index). ->note this only happens on the server and not locally.

things that i've tried: manually inserting pretty and ugly urls in the browser bar, nothing worked. actually, anything i add after .com (.com/asdfbfdgvdipgfbsd/ ) will just render the site/index page, with the path i write remaining in the bar, but content being not an error or anything else, just my main index file.

how i managed to access the videos page:

1. setting 'defaultUrl' => '/video/index' (instead of site/index), but this doesn't help as obviously i can only access this page now.
2. commenting out  'urlFormat'=>'path' ----> this allows me to get to the video page from my site/index page , but this results in the following path displayed in the browser: /video/?r=video/index. Now, in this page i display 20 video thumbnails and have included a self-loading gallery (magicScroller). locally it works fine, more thumbs being added as i scroll down. however, in this config from the server, instead of more thumbs being rendered, i am getting /site/index page rendered below the first videos batch.

here is my 'components'->UrlManager  from main.php config file:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    //'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
      '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',              
      '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
      '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

i tried adding 'enablePrettyUrl'=>true, but this results in the error: Property "CUrlManager.enablePrettyUrl" is not defined.

note. locally everything works perfect, paths look normal (no double /video/video or anything peculiar)

Not sure what else to check and try so looking forward to hearing from this community of brilliant minds:)

EDIT: 
here is the config. maybe it sheds a bit of light on my issue

```
 server {
     listen       80;
     server_name my.site.com;

     #charset koi8-r;
     access_log  /var/log/nginx/my.site.com.access main;
     root   /www/my.site.com/public;

     location / {
         index  index.html index.php;
         try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$args;
     }

     error_page  404              /404.html;

     # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
     #
     error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
     location = /50x.html {

     }

     # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
     location ~ \.php {
          fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

          #let yii catch the calls to unexising PHP files
          set $fsn /index.php;
          if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
              set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
          }

          #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
          fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/fastcgi.sock;
          include fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;

          #PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED can be omitted, but RFC 3875 specifies  them for CGI
          fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
          fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
     }

     location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml|map)$ {
         try_files         $uri $uri/ =404;
         #log_not_found     off;
         expires           1d;
     }

     # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
     # concurs with nginx's one
     #
     #location ~ /\.ht {
     #    deny  all;
     #}
 }
```

Comment: u probably know this link, anyway - check it: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Second, make sure your webserver is configured properly. E.g. check .htaccess does what you want.

Comment: link known, what about checking the webserver configuration and .htaccess? how do i do that? i don't want to make any changes that could possibly affect the functionality of other projects on that server. as i said, i m new, and if i mess something up i might not know how to revert.

Comment: .htaccess is a hidden file (because of the leading dot). It should be in your main web server directory, same spot where the index.php is. 
In the yii guide (linked above), the .htaccess is mentioned in chapter 6.
Well at least I would look now in the htaccess .. but still could be elsewhere the problem.

Comment: ok, found it. .htacces is in my root folder (/protected) . index is in (/protected/views/site/). .htaccess contains just one line ,  "deny from all"

Comment: eh no, the one in /protected is to protect that folder from access.
You need to add a .htaccess to (/protected/views/site/) .. most likely the one you already have in your local webserver, else check the Yii guide. This is not as simple as one might think. Htaccess is difficult.

Comment: will study the guide more but i pretty much followed all the rules, at least those i understood what they meant. not sure if this has anything to do with it or if it's of any importance, the server runs on nginx , not apache. in the meantime, if anyone faced this problem before and figured it out, i would very much appreciate the walkthrough

Comment: I haven't used nginx, seems its different there, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.apache-nginx-config#nginx

Comment: A part from the server configuration (Apache/Nginx), can we see how you create your links? Maybe it is also an issue with the way you create it.

Comment: To set your default controller as your video controller on Yii PHP-Framework. You must modify the core defaults controller (site/index) on your /protected/config/main.php

return array(
    'name' => 'Web Application',
    'defaultController' => 'video ', 

);

Comment: @AlexandruTrandafirCatalin , `<a href="<?php Yii::app()->createUrl("/niche/view",array("slug"=>$niche))?>">`  basic in page link,

Comment: @MdHasiburRahaman, as i said, that was the only way i could access the video page, by making it the default controller. but that is now what i want, it was only a test to see if that way it would work

Comment: @abreski how do you generate link to video page?

Comment: @AlexandruTrandafirCatalin 
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
            array('label'=>'Videos', 'url'=>array('/video/index')),
     array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
        ),
)); ?>